# glReadPixels swaps blue and red

Tags: opengl, sdl-image

I'm trying to save a screen region from opengl into a bitmap. I've tried using FreeImage, and SDL_Image, and they both require me to swap red and blue channels. Of course, that brings me to suspect that glReadPixels is the problem here...
I have this sample code:

```
bool CaptureScreenRegionToFile ( uint32_t In_X, uint32_t In_Y, uint32_t In_Width, uint32_t In_Height, std::string In_Filename )
{
GLubyte* ImageData = ( GLubyte* ) malloc ( In_Width * In_Height * 3 );
glPixelStorei ( GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1 );
glReadPixels ( In_X, In_Y, In_Width, In_Height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ImageData );

if ( CheckError() == false )
    {
    free ( ImageData );
    return false;
    }

SDL_Surface *Surface;

// JTP TODO Known bug here. Red and blue are swapped, for some reason...
Surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom ( ImageData, In_Width, In_Height, 3 * 8, In_Width * 3, 0x00FF0000, 0x0000FF00, 0x000000FF, 0 );
SDL_SaveBMP ( Surface, In_Filename.c_str() );
SDL_FreeSurface ( Surface );
free ( ImageData );

return true;
}
```

Unless I swap the red and blue channels manually after the call to CreateRGBSurfaceFrom, its colors are going to be swapped on the BMP.
Is glReadPixels supposed to do this? Am I calling it correctly?
What's wrong here?

Comment: [Possibly related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123387/loading-a-bmp-into-an-opengl-textures-switches-the-red-and-blue-colors-c-win).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`glReadPixels` works perfectly as it is intented to. When you read back the data as `GL_RGB`, you will get the following layout in memory

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  
+---------------------+
|R|G|B|R|G|B|R|G|B|...|
+---------------------+
```

Now you use `SDL_CreateRGBSurfaceFrom` with 24 bits per pixel. This will interpret every group of 3 bytes as one pixel. However, it will treat this as one big integer number, with the `rmask`, `gmask`, `bmask` and `amask. parameters describing which bits belongs to which image channel.

For example, you use `0x00FF0000` as the red mask, meaning the bits 16 to 23 will contain read (counting from least significant bit, beginning with zero):

```
 3      2|       1|       0|        0    bit 
 1      4|       6|       8|        0   number
+-----------------------------------+
|00000000|11111111|00000000|00000000|
+-----------------------------------+
  byte 3   byte 2   byte 1   byte 0
```

However, you are most likely on a [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) machine, where the least significant byte is stored in the lowest memory position. That means your `rmask` will be stored as:

```
  0    1    2    byte number
+--------------+
+ 00 | 00 | FF |
+--------------+
  R    G     B
```

so it doesn't match the format you read the pixel data from. Also note that your code is not portable, you would get different (the intented) result on a big-endian architecture.

**UPDATE 1**

If you want to write this code as protable as possible, without adding some endian-dependend `#ifdefs`, you can't use a format with 3 bytes per pixel. However, you could use `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8` or `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV`, in which each pixel is treated as a 32bit integer, and stored using the machine's native endianness. The `_REV` variant will store the first component of your format (e.g. red in `GL_RGBA`) in the least significant byte, the non-`_REV` variant in the most significant byte. In either case, you can set the appropriate masks, and it will work independently of the endianness.

Comment: Argh! I suspected as much, but hoped SDL would take care of endianness for me... That's why I also tried with 0 in all parameters ( which according to the documentation, takes care of the masks internally ), but still no avail... oh well.... thanks :)  Any idea as how to make this machine-independent easily?

Comment: @JoaoPincho: I updated my answer to try to address that.